# How to find the index of first vowel in a string?

Tags: java, string, indexing, char

I want to implement this but don't know how:
In Pig Latin, all the consonants until the first vowel should be moved to the end of the word. So while "laptop" will still be "aptoplay", "string" should become "ingStray".

I have this, the first part works just fine.

```
public static String doStuff(String word) {
    int number = 0;
    char[] vowel = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char first = word.charAt(0);
    char second = Character.toLowerCase(first);
    if (second == 'a' || second == 'e' || second == 'i' || 
            second == 'o' || second == 'u') {
        word = word + "ay";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == vowel[j]) {
                word = word.substring(i + 1) + word.substring(i) + "ay";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? are you getting errors? are you getting the wrong output? Please help us help you.

Comment: I dont get the right output.

Comment: i shoud get things like this, but i get nothing what looks close.laptop aptoplay 
Art Artay 
string ingstray 
elephant elephantay 
brinkmanship inkmanshipbray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `break` should break out of both loops. To do so, put a flag before your first loop like

```
outerloop:
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
```

Then instead of `break;` put `break outerloop;`

Second,

```
word = word.substring(i + 1) + word.substring(i) + "ay";
```

doesn't work, because when you find the vowel, you want to keep it in front, so `i + 1` should be just `i`. Then, the rest of the substring before "ay" should be the consonants at the beginning, so `0, i` instead of just `i`. In all, this gives

```
outerloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == vowel[j]) {
                word = word.substring(i) + word.substring(0, i) + "ay";
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just walk the String until you hit the first vowel, which will give you the index value you need for `String.substring()`

Simply your doStuff() method to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(doStuff("laptop"));
    System.out.println(doStuff("String"));
    System.out.println(doStuff("apple"));
}

public static String doStuff(String word) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (vowels.contains(""+word.charAt(i))) {
            String prefix = word.substring(0, i);
            String suffix = word.substring(i);
            word = suffix + prefix + "ay";
            break;
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Results:

```
aptoplay
ingStray
appleay
```

Comment: thank you, this is a very good solution.. But very different from what i was doing.. I really learnt from you so thx thx thx :-)

Comment: @mr_ecko You're welcome.  If you found that my answer was most helpful, kindly click the check mark next to my answer so your question is solved.

Comment: ""+word.charAt(i)      why the "" in this? and i found your answer second most helpfull so i marked the one below, but you did really helped me!!

Comment: @mr_ecko Because String.charAt() returns a character.  String.contains() expects a CharSequence.  The "" is an emptry String for which the character is added to becoming a String/CharSequence.

Comment: yes i understand now. Thank you again. learning this stuff is really hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check length of string, check if "aeiou" is one of the characters at the split point. If it is, reappend the string accordingly, else continue to next character.

```
String doStuff(string a)
{
    char c;
    string s = "aeiou" //y?
    int i,l;
    l=a.length();
    for(i = 0;i < l;i++)
    {   
        c=a.charAt(i);
        if(s.contains(c))
        break;
    }
    a=a.substring(i,l)+a.substring(0,i)+"ay";
    return a;
}
```

Comment: and what about "AEIOU"?

Comment: That's why I upvoted yours. Because it included what mine did not. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of new out here so not much aware of the conventions. Anyhow, the code below should be able to help you achieve the desired conversion.

Using a list of vowels provides you the 'contains' operation which allows for easier to understand code as compared to nested loops. There is no advantage in terms of processing though.

In the following code, inp is the input string.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class piglatin {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] vowels = new String[] { "A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O",
                "o", "U", "u" };
        List<String> vowelList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(vowels));
        String inp = "string";
        String returnString = inp;
        for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
            if(vowelList.contains(""+inp.charAt(i))){
                returnString = inp.substring(i)+inp.substring(0,i)+"ay";
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(returnString);
    }

}
```

Edit : Didn't realize ".contains" could be used with Strings as well as done by Shar1er80 . Now ain't stack exchange all about learning ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String pigLatin(String origianl){
            List<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<>(5);
            vowels.add('a');
            vowels.add('e');
            vowels.add('i');
            vowels.add('o');
            vowels.add('u');
            boolean vowelFound;
            for(int i = 0; i < origianl.length(); i++){
                if(vowels.contains(origianl.toLowerCase().charAt(i))){
                    String post = origianl.substring(0, i);
                    String pre = origianl.substring(i);
                    return pre + post + "ay";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

You don't have to use the list. There are plenty of other options (like using a bunch of `||` in an `if` statement). Also, it's probably better to put the `List` outside the method so it doesn't need to be created every time the method is called if possible.

Comment: @Adam made a good call. Using a `String` instead of `List` is a way better idea. The `contains` method would work the same but instead of just using `origianl.toLowerCase().charAt(i)` you could use `Character.toString(origianl.toLowerCase().charAt(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] ar = new char[] { 'u', 'o', 'i', 'e', 'a' };
        string Word = "Hello";
        int count=0;       
        for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ar.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Word[i] == ar[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",Word[i], i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count==1)
            {

                break;
            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Return the Index of the First Vowel
function firstVowelinstr(str) {
    let newstr = str.split('');
    for(i=0; i<newstr.length; i++){
        if(newstr[i] == 'a'  || newstr[i] == 'e' || newstr[i] == 'i' || newstr[i] == '0' | newstr[i] == 'u' || newstr[i] == 'A'  || newstr[i] == 'E' || newstr[i] == 'I' || newstr[i] == 'O' | newstr[i] == 'U') {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
console.log(firstVowelinstr("pInEaPPLe"))
```