# How do you take part of a string and move the first few letters to the end of the string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to take a user inputted string and move the first letters before the first vowel to the end of the string. I'm stuck here, and just need a suggestion.
This is in java by the way

Comment: Start by reading the [String API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Maybe search a little before asking the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482714/how-to-find-index-of-first-vowel-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Find the index at which the first vowel is (suppose x), then use substring..

```
String modified = mystring.substring(x, mystring.length()) + mystring.substring(0, x);
```

Read the api for what substring actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here's the main method of the program that does what you need.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s;
    int i=0;
    //presume s gets user's input here
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char c=s.charAt(i);
        if(c=='a'||c=='A'||c=='e' || ...)
        break;
    }
    if(i!=(s.length()-1)){
        for(int j=i;j<s.length();j++)
            System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
        //displays from first vowel to end of string
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("String ain't got any vowels.");
    }
}
```